# C# Proper way of periodically firing functions

Tags: c#, timer, timing

I've got about 20 functions, some of them should be fired once a second, some, 20 times a second and other twice a minute currently I have something like this:

```
                DateTime nowVar = DateTime.Now;
                var lastExecutionFunc1 = nowVar;
                var lastExecutionFunc2 = nowVar;
                var lastExecutionFunc3 = nowVar;
                var lastExecutionFunc4 = nowVar;

        DateTime _now = DateTime.Now;


                if ((_now - lastExecutionFunc1).TotalSeconds >= 0.1)
                        {
                            lastExecutionFunc1 = _now;
                            //dosomething
                        }
               if ((_now - lastExecutionFunc2).TotalSeconds >= 0.5)
                        {
                            lastExecutionFunc2 = _now;
                            //do something else
                        }
               if ((_now - lastExecutionFunc3).TotalSeconds >= 30)
                        {
                            lastExecutionFunc3 = _now;
                            //do something else
                        }
.....
```

While this works, I can't help but think that there should be a more elegant way of doing this. Creating a var to store each execution makes the core look really messy. Guess I could use  pair, but that wouldn't be too nice either.

Any advice?

EDIT: If you want to see what I'm trying to accomplish, [you can see the whole code here](https://github.com/illusive-c/FlankerTelemetry-Server/blob/master/KeyTelemetry/Form1.cs#L328). At line 525.

Comment: You can use Timer class, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: What about creating an array of functions that you can then feed directly into your timer callback based on an increasing counter?

Comment: The simplest solution is to use [Timer Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Timers are even more inelegant than what I currently have though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below code presents a basic scheduler with synchronisation lock.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Timers;

namespace TimerUsage
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Scheduler scheduler = new Scheduler();
            scheduler.ScheduleMethod(100, () => Console.WriteLine("func1"));
            scheduler.ScheduleMethod(200, () => Console.WriteLine("func2"));
            scheduler.ScheduleMethod(300, () => Console.WriteLine("func3"));
            scheduler.ScheduleMethod(1000, () => Console.WriteLine("func4"));
            scheduler.Run();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
        }

    }

    public class Scheduler
    {
        private Dictionary<int, Row> _schedule = new Dictionary<int, Row>();

        public void ScheduleMethod(int interval, Action method)
        {
            Row row;
            if (!_schedule.TryGetValue(interval, out row))
            {
                row = new Row(interval);
                _schedule[interval] = row;
            }
            row.AddMethod(method);
        }

        public void Run()
        {
            foreach (var item in _schedule)
            {
                item.Value.StartTimer();
            }
        }
    }

    internal class Row
    {
        private object _syncLock = new object();
        private Timer _timer;
        private List<Action> _methods = new List<Action>();

        public Row(int interval)
        {
            _timer = new System.Timers.Timer(interval);
            _timer.Elapsed += ExecuteItems;
        }

        private void ExecuteItems(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            lock (_syncLock)
            {
                foreach (var method in _methods)
                {
                    method();
                }
            }
        }

        public void AddMethod(Action method)
        {
            _methods.Add(method);
        }

        public void StartTimer()
        {
            _timer.Start();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Benim kullanım alanım için biraz fazla teferruatlı duruyor ama teşekkürler.

Comment: Rica ederim. Class'ı kopyalayarak kolay bir şekilde kullanabilirsiniz, teferruat kısmı kullanım zorluğu oluşturmayacaktır.

Answer (score 3):

Did you wrote an infinty loop for this timed events? Very bad practice.
If any of you "do something" lasts long, all other funtionality (and the main program) will cease working. If your functions can work indepedently, let them work indepedently and use different timer for each of them. If some functions are exclusive, use semaphors (static members) to avoid parallel working.

Comment: I don't think that's the issue here. Having 20 timers on a single form seems like a waste of resources when a single timer can handle all 20 methods. Of course, they should be `async` methods if possible.

Comment: Yep they are in while(true) block, but they work on a different thread than the main program also there is no chance for any function to take more than a few clock cycles. They just take a string from somewhere, and copy it to some other string.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it:

I've created a class that bind the method with it's interval, using the [`Action`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action(v=vs.110).aspx) delegate:

```
public class ActionInvoker
{
    private DateTime _LastRunTime;
    private Action _Action;
    private double _Interval;

    public ActionInvoker(Action action, double interval)
    {
        _Action = action;
        _Interval = interval;
        _LastRunTime = DateTime.Now;
    }


    public void InvokeAction()
    {
        var now = DateTime.Now;
        if ((now - _LastRunTime).TotalMilliseconds >= _Interval)
        {
            _LastRunTime = now;
            _Action.Invoke();
        }
    }
```

I've added a list of `ActionInvoker` as a private member of the form:

```
private List<ActionInvoker> _Actions;
```

Now, in the form's constructor, I've done this:

```
_Actions = new List<ActionInvoker>();

_Actions.Add(new ActionInvoker(DoThis, 10000));
_Actions.Add(new ActionInvoker(DoThat, 3000));
```

Now all I have in the Timer.Tick event handler is this code:

```
foreach(var ai in _Actions)
{
    ai.InvokeAction();
}
```

Of course, this is just a basic POC, you will need to develop it further if you want to send parameters to the methods, or if your methods return values.

Also note, you better run these methods as `async` to prevent the UI from freezing until they are done.

Comment: This seems like a good way to do it. But I'm not sure I understand how the "Action" business work. What am I supposed to pass to it? Btw, the functions I run doesn't take any parameters nor do they return anything. They just modify some globals. I've added a link to my project in the original post if you want to see the code.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include the link to the MSDN page for the `Action` delegate.

Comment: Yep, I've done some reading about the action type. Seems very useful, wonder how I've never noticed it till now. Thanks.

Comment: @flanker an alternative for `Action` would be `delegate` - which is more strongly typed in a sense.